# Executing ebook-convert from rails non-ascii characters display ?? in meta

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, system

I want to convert html files to epub with ebook-convert. I provide book metadata through parameters, but non-ascii characters display ?? in the book meta. I use system:

res = system cmd_line

where cmd_line is a string to be executed

When I execute the same command from command line, it works perfectly.

I use Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.13

Comment: I've found out that it works in dev mode with webrick, but fails in prod mode with passanger

Comment: this is a passenger issue, works well with thin in production mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party here but came looking for a solution to a closely related problem yesterday and so have just upvoted the question.

A possible explanation can be found at the not-obviously-applicable:
[Executing ebook-convert from rails non-ascii characters display ?? in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911552/executing-ebook-convert-from-rails-non-ascii-characters-display-in-meta)
where I've added my own take on a potential work-around.